# Moderator tools show a notification for "invisible" suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have privileges to view moderator tools and to suggest edits to tag wikis but not approve them. I just suggested a tag edit, and now I see that there's one suggested edit pending. But going to the review tool I see no suggested edits (presumably because I can't see suggested tag edits).

[image]

This makes the suggested edits count misleading, as everywhere but on the suggested edits page it appears there is one edit pending.

[image]

Since a user with this privilege set can't see these edits they shouldn't show up in the suggested edits count. I don't know if this is UX.SE behavior or all SE behavior so I thought I'd ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/number-of-suggested-edits-seems-to-include-own-edits/109634#109634) on Meta.SE explains the issue is known and explains why it's done as it is. Turns out the number of suggested edits is cached on the server for the whole site so it's always the same number, makes great sense performance-wise. Apparently a user's own suggested edits just never show up in the list.